# How to configure memcached in suitecrm Version 7.8.2

Tags: memcached, php-7, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am running Suitecrm 7.8.2 on XAMPP where PHP version is 7. I want to install Memcached on this. Is there any way to configure the Memcached on suitecrm.

Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If its not already in the **config.php** file, add the following to the **config_override.php** file, add the following:

```
  'external_cache' => 
  array (
    'memcached' => 
    array (
      'host' => '127.0.0.1',
      'port' => '11211',
    ),
  ),
```